# DoDragDrop() to windows 7 taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, taskbar, shortcut

I am trying to allow drag&drop from my program (winforms) to windows 7 taskbar (pin my program), without success.

What am I doing wrong?

```
DataObject objData = new DataObject();
objData.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true, new string[] { Application.ExecutablePath });
((Control)sender).DoDragDrop(objData, DragDropEffects.Link);
```

Answer (score 1):

I read [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/04/08/pin-items-to-the-start-menu-or-windows-7-taskbar-via-script.aspx) and [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/57480102-3d60-4071-8e12-41118cb57875) that programicly pinning items to the taskbar has been disabled intentionaly (Due to programic-spamming of the bar)

I also read [Here](http://blog.ananthonline.net/?p=37) how this can be circumvented using the shell (And you can write code that executed shell script)

Now all you need is to write the code to execute the script

**edit:** this is all the information I've found that strongly relates to your corrent problem. I can't say it'll be enought, but I'm curtain it's enough to get you started (or at least enough to help you find more information).

[A post containing code for drag&drop from application to desktop (from there it should be easy to move onto the taskbar)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/68cc6e07-295d-4df2-b74f-0421a6378b47/)
[MSDN information about DataObject (related to drag&drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx#Data_and_Data_Objects)

Comment: Thanks, but i meant to pin it by drag&drop it from my program to the taskbar, nothing in the links talking about drag & drop from my program.

Comment: What I was trying to convey is that you need to find a way to fire up an event when your object is drag&dropped to the taskbar, and inside that even you can use the above information. I'll edit my answer with some information I've found regarding dropping the data outside the application